# Issues to compile files extension .py from proto files in python (pycharm)

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, pycharm, object-detection

I have had multiple issues compiling the 35 files from the proto folder located in the path `moldes-master/research/object_detection/protos.`

I have configured the path of `protoc.exe` as environment variables in win 11. Also, I have compiled many of `.proto` files using the following code in cmd indiviudaly:

```
 protoc --python_out=.
```

However, I cannot compile these files:

```
anchor_generator.proto, box_coder.proto,box_predictor.proto,center_net.proto,
faster_rcnn.proto, matcher.proto, model.proto, pipeline.proto, post_processing.proto,
ssd.proto, target_assigner.proto, and train.proto.
```

The error message provided are:

```
* object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
* object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
* object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
* object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto: File not found.
* anchor_generator.proto:5:1: Import "object_detection/protos/flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
* anchor_generator.proto:6:1: Import "object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
* anchor_generator.proto:7:1: Import "object_detection/protos/multiscale_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
* anchor_generator.proto:8:1: Import "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto" was not found or had errors.
* anchor_generator.proto:14:5: "GridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
* anchor_generator.proto:15:5: "SsdAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
* anchor_generator.proto:16:5: "MultiscaleAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
* anchor_generator.proto:17:5: "FlexibleGridAnchorGenerator" is not defined.
```

I appreciate your help the solve this issue.